# Using the += operator with delimiter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple ASP.net program with a textbox, button and label control.

On the button click event, I'm assigning the textbox text to the label text and adding to it each time using the assignment operator. I'm delimiting the values using a comma.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += TextBox1.Text + ",";
}
```

The problem is that this code gives me an extra comma. e.g. if the values 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 are entered in the textbox, the label text will be:

```
1,2,3,4,5,
```

I need it to be:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why don't you just delete the last comma, for example by taking a substring of 0 ... length - 2.

Comment: Now I am curious, why are you adding a comma to the end of TextBox1.Text on the button click, if you are already typing commas in the textbox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you are finished, do this:

```
Label1.Text.Trim(',');
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean for "finished" please?.

Comment: meaning, before you save or do whatever you are gonna do with the Label.Text that currently has the value 1,2,3,4,5, just trim off the comma with Label1.Text.Trim(',');

Comment: Well, so the first time the trim() leaves just a 1, what happen next at the second click? you will get a "12" instead of 1,2. The OP says "each time" meaning he expects to click more than one time

Comment: No, you don't want to do it, while you are building your string.  You want to trim AFTER the user is done building string.

Comment: Fine, if the OP is OK to have that extra comma on video.

Comment: At some point the OP will need to use that string.  He's building up the string to be used later on in some action, I figure.  So when he is ready to use it, he can trim the comma

Comment: Also Steve, if you notice, he is typing the numbers in a textbox and then pressing a button. So when he presses the button, he is finished typing in the textbox, which displays the values in the Label1.Text.  So it is safe for him to just trim the comma off after he has filled in Label1.Text.  But now I ask, why is he putting a comma at the end in the first place, if he is putting commas in the textbox.

Comment: I think that the OP want to press more than one time the button, and whatever the user types, he adds the content of the textbox, then, at the second click, he adds again a new text to the label and so on and he wishes to separate every text added with a comma. (it is indifferent what the user has typed in the textbox)

Comment: Thanks all, I'm going with this solution of trimming the comma from the final string. No commas are typed into the textbox, in fact I'm validating only integer values. By trimming the final comma, I can then split the string and parse the integers to a list.

Answer (score 3):

The first time just assign the textbox.text, then add first the comma then the textbox.text

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Label1.Text.Length == 0)
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    else
        Label1.Text += "," + TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Label1.Text.Lenght <= 0)
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    else
        Label1.Text += "," + TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Append the comma first, unless the label is blank

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Label1.Text))
        Label1.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    else
        Label1.Text += "," + TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text += (Label1.Text.Length == 0 ? "" : "," ) + TextBox1.Text;
}
```

This way you prepend a comma to the added text only if the label is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
Label1.Text += string.IsNullOrEmpty(Label1.Text) ? TextBox1.Text : string.Format(",{0}", TextBox1.Text);
```